# Laravel - how to use belongsToMany relationship using second index and not primary key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, foreign-keys

#### App overview

I'm learning Laravel and my dummy app allows users to log issues against projects. A project can have many issues and an issue can have many tags assigned to it.

I'm currently working on `projects/show.blade.php` which outputs all issues associated with a project in an HTML table with columns for `name` and `tags`.

#### Issue

I've setup 'belongs to many' relationships so that my `issues`, `tags` and `issues_tags` (intermediary) tables can talk to each other but I've run into a problem whereby tags are being output against the wrong issues.

The problem stems from the fact that my `issues` table (by design) includes an `item_id` column, which is an index but not the primary key. I use `item_id` for routing/display on the frontend because I wanted the issue ID that users see to start from 1 for every new project added instead of being sequential and everyone knowing how many there are in the database.

For example, tags assigned to issue #3 are called using `issues.id` and not `issues.item_id`.

#### Sample data

[image: Sample data]

**What I want:** Tag_id's 1, 2 and 3 to be assigned to issue 3 where `issues.item_id` is the index upon which to match. E.g.

[image: Correct result]

**What I am getting:** Tag_id's 1, 2 and 3 are assigned to issue 3 but are retrieved using `issues.id` as the index to match against. E.g.

[image: Incorrect result]

#### Code

**Issues migration**

```
    Schema::create('issues', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('item_id')->index()->unsigned();
        $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->longText('description');
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->default('1');
        $table->integer('created_by');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Tags migration**

```
Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Issues tags migration**

```
Schema::create('issues_tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags');
    $table->integer('issue_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('issue_id')->references('item_id')->on('issues');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Issue model**

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'issues_tags');
}
```

**Tag model**

```
public function issues()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Issue', 'issues_tags', 'issue_id')->withPivot('item_id');
}
```

**View (projects/show.blade.php)**

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Item ID</th>
      <th>Issue</th>
      <th>Tags</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($issues as $issue)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $issue->id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $issue->item_id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $issue->name }}</td>
      <td>
        @foreach($issue->tags as $tag)
          <span class="badge badge-primary">{{ $tag->name }}</span>
        @endforeach
      </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </table>
```

---

#### Question

How can I use `issues.item_id` instead of `issues.id` when using a belongsToMany relationship in Laravel?

Comment: Have you created model relationships? Please past your relationship code here

Comment: Knew I was forgetting something. I have added the models. The Issues Tags model is an empty class - I've not added anything to it.

Comment: I updated example in the question to help explain the issue better.

Comment: @Nutic was on the right lines. I ended up using this in my Issue model: `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'issues_tags', 'issue_id', 'tag_id', 'item_id');`

Answer (score 1):

From source code:

```
/**
     * Define a many-to-many relationship.
     *
     * @param  string  $related
     * @param  string  $table
     * @param  string  $foreignPivotKey
     * @param  string  $relatedPivotKey
     * @param  string  $parentKey
     * @param  string  $relatedKey
     * @param  string  $relation
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function belongsToMany($related, $table = null, $foreignPivotKey = null, $relatedPivotKey = null,
                                  $parentKey = null, $relatedKey = null, $relation = null)
```

You can override any params, Laravel just puts defaults made from table names in there if you do not specify which one to use.

In your case it would be:

In Model/Issue.php

```
public function tags() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'tag_id', 'issue_id');
}
```

In Model/Tag.php

```
public function issues() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(Issue::class, 'issue_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have put the model relationship code for the issues tags model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Eloquent;

class IssueTag extends Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'issues_tags';

    public function issues()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Issue', 'issue_id', 'item_id');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Tag', 'tag_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: This produces the same result as before.  I don't see how this is going to get the relationship looking at `issues.item_id` instead of `issues.id`

Comment: Try to hasMany instead of belongsTo

Comment: My code is perfect You need to change in your tag and issues model hasMany instead of belongsTo

Comment: I have just updated this line return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Issue', 'issue_id', 'item_id'); Please check now